# Microsoft sculpt keyboard unresponsive on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, usb

This is really frustrating me. I have a Microsoft Sculpt USB keyboard and have just got a new Macbook Pro with touch bar, and it is just not pairing with the keyboard.

The keyboard connects via a Nano tranceiver, which is plugged into my USB-C port via an adaptor. I can see that this is successfully connected in my system information: 
[image: system information]

The first time I connected the keyboard, I got a keyboard setup assistant dialogue as described in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144395/microsoft-sculpt-keyboard-on-os-x) prompting me to press some keys on the keyboard to set it up. When I press the keys as requested, nothing happens.

Now, nothing pops up, and the keyboard is just completely unresponsive. However, I can see the keyboard is there as one of my input sources when I click 'Modifier Keys...' in my keyboard system preferences: [image].

Really pretty stuck on what to do here. I can't find any drivers or other settings that I might change to fix this.

Comment: See this [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273727/microsoft-surface-ergonomic-keyboard-not-recognized-as-a-proper-keyboard/273837#273837).  The Sculpt keyboard on MS' website dosen't list El Cap or Sierra as being supported.

Comment: OK wow so it literally just won't work. I know it was working with my last MBP, but quite possibly that was still on Yosemite...

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It works for me on my new MacBook with macOS 10.13.2 (17C88), Kernel-Version: Darwin 17.3.0

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I use a new Macbook Pro with touch bar. I had to keep playing around with which USB or USB-c port I was plugging the receiver into, and the dongle adapter / usb hub into. Could never find the sweet spot to it working. On my old macbook that was also running Sierra, it worked fine. But it definitely needed to be plugged into a certain usb port. So I think the issue is the USB-c system, not the OS.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.themtparty.com/karabiner-settings-microsoft-sculpt-keyboard/

the Karabiner download allowed my Sculpt keyboard to work on my El Capitan system.  I'm excited as the keyboard suddenly stopped working a few weeks ago for no reason.  Happy for this download, will donate coffee $ as suggested